# How to change Font Awesome props with respect to media queries in React.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I had a Font-Awesome component in React.js where I had to control the size of the icon with respect to some media queries, so basically how do we change the size of the Font-Awesome component :

```
export const Revenue = (props) => (
  <div className={classes.Div}>
    <div>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
        size="3x"                      //   @media(max-width: 415px) { size= 2x} and 3x for other
        icon={faDollarSign}
        color="#01CBC6"
      />
    </div>

    <div
      className={classes.SmallDiv}
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      <h3>{props.data.totalRevenue}</h3>
      <p>Total Revenue</p>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the documentation for `FontAwesomeIcon`, and I don't think it supports that out of the box.

Since you are using CSS modules, you can still supply the `FontAwesomeIcon` with your custom styles, and this can be done by adding the right classes to `className`.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
  icon={faDollarSign}
  className={classes.dollarIcon}
/>
```

And then, on your css module file, you will need to define the CSS properties:

```
.dollarIcon {
  // add the rest here
  @media (max-width: 415px) { 
    height: ....;
    width: ....;
  }
}
```